# Emulate a browser to access Google Trends data

Tags: r

I am trying to download data from Google Trends in R. The approach [here](http://christophriedl.net/2013/08/22/google-trends-with-r/) works, but only for a couple of times before I hit a quota limit (and I wasn't even running a batch job).

In the meantime, I am able to still get output from Google Trends in the browser. Hence my interest: is there a way for R to emulate browser, such that I can access the data in R as per in browser (Chrome, if it matters) ?

Comment: `RCurl`? `httr`? `Rselenium`? `GTrendsR`? I'd say try some of these packages and come back with the results. :-)

Comment: The link in my message uses `Rcurl`, and as I said it worked for a couple of times (I believe it was 3 times) and then hit a quota limit.

I tried `GTrendsR` replicating code from https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/11/24/gtrendsr-package-to-explore-google-trending-for-field-dependent-terms/ , didn't work, saying "No Trends data for <term>" for all terms -  presumably also blocked because of quota.

I'm not familiar with Selenium and it seems an overkill to pick it up for this since I'm unlikely to use it further.

I can use some tips on how to do this with `httr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open links from R with the browser using `browseURL()`. Use the function below to create the link.

```
URL_GT=function(keyword="", country=NA, region=NA, year=NA, month=1, length=3){
# keyword can contain up to five words
# country is the 2 letter country code
# region is also a 2 letter code
# year: if you want a specific year, put it here
# month: starting month if you have specified the year
# length: the number of months you want if you have specified the year

  start="http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en-US&q="
  end="&cmpt=q&content=1&export=1"
  geo=""
  date=""

#Geographic restrictions
  if(!is.na(country)) {
    geo="&geo="
    geo=paste(geo, country, sep="")
    if(!is.na(region)) geo=paste(geo, "-", region, sep="")
  }

  queries=keyword[1]
  if(length(keyword)>1) {
    for(i in 2:length(keyword)){
    queries=paste(queries, "%2C ", keyword[i], sep="")
    }
  }

#Dates
  if(!is.na(year)){
    date="&date="
    date=paste(date, month, "%2F", year, "%20", length, "m", sep="")
  }

  URL=paste(start, queries, geo, date, end, sep="")
  URL <- gsub(" ", "%20", URL)
  return(URL)
}

url <- URL_GT('stackoverflow')
browseURL(url)
```

If you want to download a lot of files, take a look at [these helper functions](https://github.com/321k/Google-Trends/blob/master/Google%20Trends%20functions).

Comment: Thanks! Yes I did manage to get it to work earlier using `browseURL()`. The helper functions looked good, I'll use them the next time I need to raid GoogleTrends again!

Comment: I am wondering how to use this. Can you please tell me how to use this script to get the download link? Thanks